# Application crashed when run from exe file and I am not able to log it

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know why yet but when I run application from exe file just by double-clicking on exe application crashes. When I run application by simply from Visual Studio application works fine.

I tried to log errors but I can't so I am not able to find out what is wrong...
I used this:

```
Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Path.Combine(logs, "lD.dat")));
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Path.Combine(logs, "lT.dat")));
```

This is an `WPF` application was working correctly before. But then I was ask to port to to be `Prism` Module. Then it started crashes. But again i decided to port it back to be classic `WPF` Application but it still crashes when run from EXE file but when run from Visual Studio works fine.

I was checking namespaces, code, names, everything but still it doesn't help.

Maybe you now how I could log an error application does?

This is what I was only able to see when I set `WPF` app to print to console.
But as we can see this is only a part of error...

Below is the error screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in your windows event log that could shed some light on it?

Comment: Are you using the exe from `\bin\Debug` or `\obj\Debug`

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the correct EXE? Maybe you're trying to run the `*.vshost.exe` file instead?

Comment: Hi, I am running application from \bin\Debug, and correct exe file.

Comment: I added screenshot of console output.

Comment: Your screenshot is missing the key starting part of stack trace that could provide a reason for your issue. Judging by what I can see, I can only assume that you have multiple threads running in your application and that one of them is trying to access something that is not accessible to it. When your application crashes, try to get the actual stack trace text from the crash dialog and paste it here instead of screenshot.

Comment: Hi lightbuilb, I know that but I am not able to do it unfortunately. Application crashes instantly so I am not able to take text from console as you can see it's grayed out.

Comment: Additionally why when I run application from Visual Studio it works fine if from exe fine it doesn't just strange to me.

Comment: When you build your application from VS, can you confirm the output path and exe name is same as the one you're running (use the Output window in VS)?